# How do I use node.js docx library to get NativeDocuments to render numbered lists when converting from docx to pdf?

Tags: node.js, pdf-generation, docx, docx-wasm

I used the following page as an example to generate the docx.
https://github.com/dolanmiu/docx/blob/master/docs/usage/numbering.md

(docx)

```
PRE-DECLARATIONS
1.  Previous Wills & Codicils
    I revoke all previous wills and codicils.
2.  Marital Status
```

Then used the serverless function from NativeDocuments to convert from docx to pdf.
https://github.com/NativeDocuments/docx-to-pdf-on-AWS-Lambda

(generated pdf)

```
PRE-­DECLARATIONS
Previous Wills & Codicils
    I revoke all previous wills and codicils.
Marital Status
```

The following is the js code I have used to generate the numbered list

```
const numbering = new Numbering();
const abstractNum = numbering.createAbstractNumbering();
abstractNum.createLevel(0, "upperRoman", "%1", "start").addParagraphProperty(new Indent(720, 260));
abstractNum.createLevel(1, "decimal", "%2.", "start").addParagraphProperty(new Indent(1440, 980));
abstractNum.createLevel(2, "lowerLetter", "%3)", "start").addParagraphProperty(new Indent(2160, 1700));
const concrete = numbering.createConcreteNumbering(abstractNum);

doc.createParagraph('Previous Wills & Codicils').setNumbering(concrete, 0);

const packer = new Packer(doc, undefined, undefined, numbering);
```

Comment: Could you please put your generated docx somewhere accessible?

Comment: is the company still alive ? their website seems down